# How to add image upload field in django rest swagger

Tags: django, rest, swagger

I am using Django rest swagger. Added a image filed to serializer which appears in rest framework UI. But do not appear in Swagger UI.

Added the following field in serializer.
      upload_photo = serializers.ImageField( required=False)

But swagger showing a simple text field. While rest framework showing a upload field. Can anyone help me to show upload field in swagger ui as well

Comment: hey, I got the same problem, have you find the solution ?

Comment: No i have used Django rest framework to upload the file. Django rest swagger ha limitation in file uploading and using key as list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a file field you can override th YAML doctstring for the field:

```
parameters:
    -
      name: file
      type: file
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the image url instead works way better, the ImageField gave me endless issues as well you can call the image by upload_photo.url returns the same value as upload_photo in normal text

Answer (score 0):

you should change your parser like this :

```
from rest_framework import permissions, viewsets
from rest_framework.mixins import (CreateModelMixin, DestroyModelMixin,
                                   ListModelMixin, RetrieveModelMixin)
from rest_framework.parsers import FormParser, MultiPartParser
from .models import Customer
from .permissions import CustomerPermission
from .serializer import CustomerSerializer


class CustomerViewSet(CreateModelMixin, ListModelMixin, RetrieveModelMixin, 
                      DestroyModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    permission_classes = [CustomerPermission]
    queryset = Customer.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CustomerSerializer
    parser_classes = (FormParser, MultiPartParser)
```

after that you can check your swagger :
[image]

Comment: Hi, could you please elaborate how and why this fixes the issue?